# RoI cropping in Spatial Transformer Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, spatial-transformer-network

TL;DR: How does RoI cropping method from Spatial Transformer Network works?

Reading PyTorch [Spatial Transformer Network tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/spatial_transformer_tutorial.html) I saw the network uses a special RoI pooling I haven't seen before called RoI cropping.
Reading the docs for the `F.affine_grid` and `F.grid_sample` did not explain so much what is happening there, so I tried reading the network's [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02025.pdf) in hope to understand as well as some [blog post](http://www.telesens.co/2018/03/11/object-detection-and-classification-using-r-cnns/#Crop_Pooling) on Faster RCNN elaborating on the method with pictures, but still no help.
I feel every source has different details and can't get the idea of what exactly is happening there, as good as I understand the normal RoI pooling and align methods.

Right now, this is the big picture in my head:
1. As usual, map the suggested RoI coordinates to the feature map space.
2. Normalize the coordinates to the range of [-1, 1] (I guess that's for the following affine transformation).
3. Calculate (using the method in the picture below) the transformation values.
4. Now, I assume we apply the transformation to the RoI pixels?
5. And finally, I assume we do an interpolation (i.e. bilinear interpolation) to the final coordinates.

Could someone briefly explain the whole process of the RoI cropping method? I feel I might be missing something.

[image]